# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 110806 A distributed query failed

Tags: azure-synapse

An ETL developer was running an UPDATE statement on a relatively large table and reports it failed with:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 110806;A distributed query failed: Distribution(s):[1-60]The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.
>   Operation cancelled by user.

Is this caused by a client-initiated abort due to runtime limit being exceeded or did the error originate in the database?

Comment: I don't think `UPDATE` and columnstore are a great combination.  Have you considered doing this as a CTAS?

Comment: Agreed.  Consistently trying to educate developers on need to minimize transaction size (etc), but unsure if this failure was "self-inflicted" in a timeout sense or the database caused the error.

Comment: An exception like this is ambiguous, and with this amount of detail, it's impossible to tell whether or not it's client or db side. If this is a consistent problem even with smaller transaction sizes, you can always [file a ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket) so that an engineer can look into the telemetry. That being said, wBob is right about best practices.